# Find the volume of a body bounded by $z = x^2 + 3y^2, z= 8-x^2-5y^2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the body bounded by the elliptic paraboloids $z = x^2 + 3y^2, z= 8-x^2-5y^2$.

What i did?

> First of all i intersected two functions and got the desire area is a ellipse $x^2+4y^2=4$  on $xy$ plane.

later i did polar conversations and i got this:

> $$x^2+4y^2=4\longrightarrow r^2=4,~~ \theta\in[0,2\pi]$$ or $$r\in [0..\ 2],~~\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$ So we have: $$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{2}\int_{z_1}^{z_2}r dr d\theta$$
>   $$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{2}2(4-r^2)r dr d\theta$$

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes.  At first note that the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=4$ is the **projection** on the $xy$ plane of the intersection curve, but this curve does not stay in this plane. As an example the height $z$ of a point on this curve with $y=0$ is $z=4$ but the height of a point with $x=0$ is $z=3$.

Also, your conversion to polar (or cylindrical ?) coordinates is not correct because in this system we have $r^2=x^2+y^2$ so that $x^2+4y^2=r^2(\cos^2 \theta+4\sin^2 \theta)$

Anyway I dubt that a conversion to spherical coordinates gives a simpler integration because the problem has not a spherical symmetry.

In Cartesian coordinates you can note that the limits for $z$ are:
$$
x^2+3y^2\le z\le 8-x^2-5y^2
$$

and, from the equation of the ellipse, we can find the limits for $x$:

$$
-2\sqrt{1-y^2} \le x \le 2\sqrt{1-y^2}
$$

and these are real numbers if $y$ has limits
$$
-1 \le y \le 1
$$

so we can find the volume as the triple integral:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-2\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{2\sqrt{1-y^2}} \int _{x^2+3y^2}^{8-x^2-5y^2}dzdxdy
$$

Comment: Your awesome thank you :)

Comment: Just to complete: $V= 8 \pi$

Comment: Miss a nice illustrating plot here +1